# Vote in the moderator elections!

Tags: discussion, status-completed

### **VOTE!**

As of this posting, there are 2 hours to go in the
[moderator elections](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).
There are 516 people eligible to vote, of whom 121 have voted, for
a turnout rate of **23%**.

That's pretty low: let's fix it.

To give you some sense of proportion: 23% was also the turnout
rate for
[Egypt's 2005 presidential election](http://www.idea.int/vt/countryview.cfm?id=69),
which Hosni Mubarak won in a landslide.